# Formatting the output of a collection

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
$servers = Get-Content "servers.txt"
$collection = $()
foreach ($server in $servers)
{

    $status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f G) }
    if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
    {
        $status["Results"] = "Online"
        $test = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 4 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
        $stat = $test | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average -Maximum -Minimum
        $status["Avg"] = $stat.Average
        $status["Lost"] = [string]$(100*(4-$test.Count)/4) + ' %'

    } 
    else 
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Down" 
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
    $collection += $serverStatus 
}
$collection | Out-GridView | Export-Csv -LiteralPath .\ServerStatus3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

how do I output as a table? but so that the columns are in a particular sequence

If I delete the "Lost" column, it is displayed as a table. [See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCVhU.png)
But as you can see, the first column is not displayed completely.
The most important thing that I need is for each integration to be displayed immediately on the screen!

Comment: `$collection | Select-Object -Property <insert fields here in desired order> | Out-GridView | [...]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for just formatting, you can use `Format-Table` with `-Wrap` Parameter.

But if you use format table, you will lose the Object structure and the result will be just text and can't be exported to a CSV file.

$collection | Out-GridView | Export-Csv -LiteralPath .\ServerStatus3.csv -NoTypeInformation

The above line of code will generate an empty csv file. You have to put `-Passthru` parameter to `Out-GrifView`, I would suggest not to use `Out-GridView` as it will break the automation here.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can build an object directly

   2. You should be storage value without unity for average or lost (unity is for print, storage always without unity -> if a day you want use this value not necessary to re-split this string)
   3. Not nessary to pass by an array, write your object on output and use with pipe

try this:

```
Get-Content "c:\temp\servers.txt" |  %{

    if (Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
    {
         $test = Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 4 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

         [pscustomobject]@{
         ServerName=$_
         Results="Online"
         TimeStamp=Get-Date
         Avg=($test | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).Average
         PercentLost=100*(4-$test.Count)/4
         }
    } 
    else 
    { 
         [pscustomobject]@{
         ServerName=$_
         Results="Down"
         TimeStamp=Get-Date
         Avg=$null
         PercentLost=$null
         }
    } 

} | export-csv "c:\temp\resultstats.csv" -notype
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how to make it output every line consecutively to the console? If I put instead of `export-csv` `ft -AutoSize`, then prints the table at the very end, but I want to immediately see the execution.

Comment: $result=get_content.......     at the end, add $result for print to screen